# RxJava2 - Combine multiple Singles emitted results into a Map

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I fetch a `List<User>` from the server.

```
class User {
  Long localId;
  String remoteId;
  ..
}
```

I need to insert each user from the **list** into the **local db**, and in the end get a `HashMap<String,Long>` (an object that maps `remoteId` to `localId`)

Each `insertToLocalDb` returns a `Single<Long>`. Thus, the `Observable` emits the inserted `User`'s `localId`

How can I achieve this in a reactive way?

Comment: What code do you have so far? There are plenty of examples with the rx-java and rx-java2 tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all I have to suggest using a transaction for multiple db operations, which is your case.

A trivial non-performant solution might look like this:

```
fetchUsers()
  .flatMap { users ->
        Observable.fromIterable(users)
            .flatMapSingle { user -> dao.save(user) }
            .toList()
            .map { databaseIds ->
                val remoteIds = users.map { it.remoteId }
                databaseIds.zip(remoteIds).toMap()
            }
```

But taking transaction in mind, `Room` supports this for example, it can go like this:

```
fetchUsers().flatMap { users ->
        dao.saveAll(users) // typically returns Single<List<Long>>
            .map { databaseIds ->
                val remoteIds = users.map { it.remoteId }
                databaseIds.zip(remoteIds).toMap()
            }
    }
```

Both will result to `Single<Map<String, Long>>`, but the second approach is far more performant if you're using a transaction.